# ObjectMapper - String JSON to java object with sublevel arrays

Tags: java, arrays, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to de-serialize the json string to objects, and facing an issue where I have array of objects in sub level.
I looked into the below stackoverflow links where they have designed one class and classes with in that for each sub level; and used List<> for array of data.
I have used the same but have seprate classes for each object (separate java files)

[Json string parsing to java object with multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656123/json-string-parsing-to-java-object-with-multiple-objects)

[How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Let me give you a vision of my code:

**JSON for Person details**

```
{
"name" : "abcd",
"age" : 30,
"addressList" : {
   "count" : 2,
   "data" : [
     {
      "state" : "NY",
      "city" : "Bronx"
     },
     {
      "state" : "NJ",
      "city" : "Chestnut"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

**Classes**

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private AddressList addressList;

    public Person() { }

    //getters and setters
}

public class AddressList {
    private int count;
    private List<Address> data;

    public AddressList() { }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Address {
    private String state, city;

    public Address() { }

    //getters and setters
}
```

In my main class, doing like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Defect defect = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);
```

Now, All the values are loading properly except the address list. Even I tried `Address[]` instead of `List<Address>` in `AddressList.java` but no luck.
Can anyone give me some ideas on this or what could be the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry for the confusion. it's a typo. Corrected it in json.

Comment: `JSON` payload fits given `Java` `POJO`s classes. There must be a problem  somewhere else.

Comment: It was my mistake. Upon rechecking entire JSON, had one field with wrong name, somehow missed as it was big json.
Thanks anyway for all.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the structure above should work fine as pointed out in comments area. Initially didn't work for me because I have missed to notice on of my field name was wrong, by correcting that working like charm.